# How do I remove a section of a wall created with Archipack?

Tags: modeling, add-on, archipack-add-on

I activated Archipack add-on. With that add-on I just made a simple rectangular shape with 1,2,3,4 walls numbers. And I just want to delete the 2 number wall only to make a U shape. I do not want to recreate the walls again just to delete the 2 number wall. When I press remove from the N panel it just created a triangular shape. Without loosing the shape I just want to delete the 2 no wall. How can I achieve is there any other option?

**Cut or delete this wall**

[image]

**Get this U Shape**

[image]

[image]

Un-tick the close button

[image]

Comment: Untick the close option.

Comment: @sambler i tried with the untick close option same result image also posted in question